# Язык Си не компилируется в Sublime Text 3 и даже в командной строке

Tags: c, компиляция

Путь к `gcc` добавил в `PATH`
Файл сохранил в (`*.c`, `*.h`) в командной строке такая ошибка:

> gcc: error: 1.c: No such file or directory
>   
>   gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.

В **Sublime Text 3** такая ошибка:

> 1: file not recognized: File format not recognized
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   [Finished in 0.3s]

Для **Sublime Text 3** все делал по этому [ролику](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjkT-Ng5LYQ).

Буду благодарен хоть за что-то одно.

Comment: `gcc: error: 1.c: No such file or directory` - говорит, нет такого файла в текущей папке. Что выдает `dir` (на линуксе - `ls`) в этой папке?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо роликов почитать про проекты в саблайме. Но перед этим почитайте о конфигах саблайма.  Лично от меня - лучше собирать все ручками в терминале :) пишите make файлы или ознакомьтесь с CMake

Comment: Ошибка что нету файла 1.c - у Вас пути не настроены к исходникам

Comment: Чтобы дать Вам конкретный ответ - подтвердите что пользуетесь Linux

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно ничего добавлять просто скачай , gcc compiler для своей архитектуры , и просто перейди в директорию с файлом (допустим) main.c  . Вводишь gcc main.c , после создается файл a.exe , вводишь в cmd a.exe программа запустилась , у меня лично так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш ответ не корректен. 1. Cmd в Gnu/Linux? 2. Gcc уже содержит слово compiler. 3. Для правильной сборки лучше писать make-файл или генерировать его - например CMake’ом

Comment: Это для тех у кого винда